# Function and parameters part of a quiz

Tags: function

If you were displaying quiz questions and answers what would put for:
Function name:
Parameters needed:
Returned:
Local variables needed: 
Description of function

Answer (score 0):

What language are you working in? If you can tell me that I can give you an example.

Function names usually describe what the function is doing. In example gradeTest() grades the test.

Parameters are what are passed from outside the function into the function. gradeTest(answerOne, answerTwo) <- answerOne, answerTwo would be parameters being passed to the function to use.

Local variables are variables only used within the scope of where they are defined. If you create a variable inside a function it is only available inside the function. Heres a good description -> 
https://docs.thunderstone.com/site/vortexman/variable_scope_global_vs_local.html

**Edit:**

```
answerKey = ["air","water", "london"]
testTaker = input("What is your name?")

''' 
def adminQuiz(name, answers): is an example of a function that administers a quiz.
The quiz takes two parameter the name of the test taker and the answer key.

testTaker -> name 
answerKey -> answers
'''

def adminQuiz(name, answers):
  # Welcome message to the test taker
  print ("Welcome to the Quiz " + name + "! Lets begin!")
  # answers are assigned to local variables inside this function and used to compare to the correct answers from the key
  #
  # Question I
  responseOne = input("What do you breath?")
  if (answers[0] == responseOne):
    print ("You answered " + responseOne + " and that is correct.")
  else: 
    print ("You answered " + responseOne + " and that is not correct." + " The correct answer is " + answers[0])
  # Question II
  responseTwo = input("What is the ocean made of?")
  if (answers[1] == responseTwo):
    print ("You answered " + responseTwo + " and that is correct.")
  else: 
    print ("You answered " + responseOne + " and that is not correct." + " The correct answer is " + answers[1])
  # Question III
  responseThree = input("What is the capital of the United Kingdom?")
  if (answers[2] == responseThree):
    print ("You answered " + responseThree + " and that is correct.")
  else: 
    print ("You answered " + responseThree + " and that is not correct." + " The correct answer is " + answers[2])
  # return statement to complete function and let user know the quiz is over.
  return "We've completed the quiz!"

quiz = adminQuiz(testTaker, answerKey)
print (quiz)

'''
Function name: adminQuiz

Parameters needed: name, answers

Returned: a message declaring the quiz is over

Local variables needed: labels for user input ex. responseOne, responseTwo, responseThree

Description of function:

A function is a block of organized, reusable code that is used to perform a single related action. 
'''
```

You can try this example out here:

https://repl.it/@chaosmaths1/PythonQuizEx

Comment: Hi sorry I'm using python

Comment: @JadeM I've posted an update. if I can clarify any part please don't hesitate to ask!